# Error: invalid address during truffle migration process in Rinkeby network

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, migration, rinkeby

I can't deploy my contract to Rinkeby network through `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby`.

My truffle.js file looks like this:

`{
    networks: {
        rinkeby: {
            {
                from       : 'my_unlocked_and_non_empty_wallet_address',
                network_id : 4,
                gas        : 2700000,
                gasPrice   : 20000000000,
                host       : "localhost",
                port       : 8545
            }
        }
    }
}`

Geth node is running inside Docker at the same host where I try to deploy. I've successfully connected to this node via truffle console.

When I run `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby` I have an error:

> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
>     Deploying Migrations...
>     ... 0x076235e944e70e561a0b9b6b14307157d07775d67a46689e44ffaf7675829b84
>   /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:30534
>       throw new Error('invalid address');
>       ^
>
> Error: invalid address
>       at inputAddressFormatter (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:30534:11)
>       at /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36660:28
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at Method.formatInput (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36659:32)
>       at Method.toPayload (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36685:23)
>       at Eth.send [as getCode] (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36710:30)
>       at Object.callback (/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:241521:39)
>       at /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36713:25
>       at /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:243485:9
>       at /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:78847:11

Contract creation transaction from output can be founded here: [0x076235e944e70e561a0b9b6b14307157d07775d67a46689e44ffaf7675829b84](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x076235e944e70e561a0b9b6b14307157d07775d67a46689e44ffaf7675829b84)

There is a result of little debugging *cli.bundled.js* file.

This is what I get whe try to deploy in *testrpc* network:

> ... 0x34865735e70707919805f2850b823e67adb25ff0fe059d5ece5836d9430a7208
>   [ [Function: inputAddressFormatter],   [Function:
>   inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter] ] [
>   '0x97280c75faa2e7e1b2a182e34fffcb77c58b9b56' ]   Migrations:
>   0x97280c75faa2e7e1b2a182e34fffcb77c58b9b56

And in *Rinkeby* network:

> ... 0xa2a4697161936052f320bbce9171600741cf155785d25ecf45d914f1445be648
>   [ [Function: inputAddressFormatter],   [Function:
>   inputDefaultBlockNumberFormatter] ] [ null ]

As we can see, in the case of Rinkeby we have null instead of valid contract address. But... why has it happened?

Ok, I went deeper.

So, when executes this line (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/7560f273359071afae31d010b97fa1872dacd66c/lib/web3/contract.js#L119) of web3.js code (line 222802 in Truffel's *cli.bundled.js*) we are getting answer with *null* in *contractAddress* field.

For example:

`{ 
  blockHash: '0xd08cee7ec0d9e50185099ca403b53798081f94ba73bbb9caa7a72fa2afb2591f',
  blockNumber: 696482,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 201492,
  from: '0xdc2e0c6e3d08bc53200ea0a90ec4f550d9d1f616',
  gasUsed: 0,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  root: '0x4ae760bf36bd646016db7018f16f6e5fadc2200aee17a89337b6d0a26534fb03',
  to: null,
  transactionHash: '0x6863a10cc9e42f62056f5defebd9f249ced92c024c1cb2ed94ae1a1efb1a5cc5',
  transactionIndex: 0 
}`

And example for testrpc which works properly:

`{ 
  transactionHash: '0x55bb0dc39488b897ced17831ff6308741045b463993d3b2d239748434b134b89',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0xa04dc4a145b6884dfa78cfc4d55888b4e6c2ed41b8888cff72458728b474f6da',
  blockNumber: 15,
  gasUsed: 201262,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 201262,
  contractAddress: '0x0bfed93fdbcd00323918ad1d361cd999ba291ce4',
  logs: []
 }`

Comment: Also [raised on GitHub](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/534).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the reason.
*contractAddress* is *null* because I'm using geth node in embedded/light mode - it hasn't enough information about blockchain.
Issue may be closed.